# Rails `load': cannot load such file (Rails) when trying to create a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When trying to create a new project in rails I get the following error:

```
 MacBook-Air-van-Reinier:Dev reinierverbeek$ rails new project
/Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails-5.0.0.1/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/reinierverbeek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have been using Rails for a while and have created many projects in rails before without a problem. I have tried several things.

> gem install rails

This did not work, then I tried

> gem uninstall rails + gem install rails

then I tried

> gem update

then I tried

> bundle install

`rails s` and `rails -v` do work after I run `bundle install` in an old project folder. But outside such a folder `rails -v` and `rails new myProject`, return above error.

`gem list` shows that the rails gem is installed: `rails (5.0.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.2.6)`

I recently installed jruby + rails (seperate installation was required for Jruby), but I am not sure if this is related to the issue. Any ideas what my issue could be?

Comment: It could be a RVM related issue. Try unistalling and reinstalling RVM (or switching to RBenv)

Comment: After trying a lot of things, I just found a dirty solution which was to install an older version of ruby trough rvm (2.2.3) and re-install rails under this version. Does this seem related? Would you still recommend to uninstall RVM and install everything from scratch? Does re-installing RVM here mean imploding, also deleting all gems and versions of Ruby?

Comment: Not sure - RoR runs on MRI Ruby 2.3+ so something is screwy with RVM or your load paths or even that build of ruby.